# Does auto layout effect how things look when changing simulated metrics size?

Tags: ios, autolayout

I created an auto layout constraint of a label to the right edge of a UITableView.  when I changed the simulated metrics size of the table view controller from iPhone 5.5-inch to 4.7-inch I was expecting the label to stay put right at the edge of the new smaller scree, but it is pushed off the screen to the right. Is this the expected behavior?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the scene of this ViewController, go on to resolve auto layout option. There, select the update frames option and click on fix misplacement. This will bring your label on the right edge.

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by "on the scene" of the ViewController? when i click on the view controller in interface builder, the Editor-->update frames option is grayed out.

Comment: click on the label and then check the option.

Comment: I was able to click "update frames" for the label, but when I do this it is only fixed until I change the simulate metrics size again, and it goes back to being off centered.

Comment: @FierceMonkey yes, you have to adjust the frames every time you change the simulated metrics size.

Comment: @FierceMonkey please accept the answer if it was helpful